# Don't packages have to match the subdirectories the java file is in?

Tags: java, package

I was writing some practice programs for my java certification this morning, and noticed that I had mistyped a package name, so it didn't match the subdirectory the java file was in. I compiled the code expecting an error, but everything compiled file -- not even a warning.

I googled around a bit, and most of the pages I read said that the package name had to match the subdirectory. My experience shows that's not the case.

When I attempted to run the program, it didn't work because the .class file was in the wrong directory. I moved it to the correct directory, and got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sample/directory
/doesnt/even/exist/OtherPackageMemberModifiers (wrong name: com/sample/chap01/O
therPackageMemberModifiers)
```

So what I think I'm seeing is that Java code will *compile* if the package and the subdirectory don't match up, but there doesn't seem to be a way to run the code if you do that. Is that correct?

Comment: The phenomenon that package path and directory path are redundant shows its nasty head. The compiler would have been right to issue an error. However that would not be 100%: package src.main.java.com.sample ... or package com.sample. ... still would both raise no error. Javac would need to be directory based (-d) and it is basically file based.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The package name has to match the directory name in order for the *class* file to be found correctly. It doesn't *have* to match the directory name at compilation time for some compilers (e.g. javac) although others (such as Eclipse) will at least give a warning.

The "way to run the code if you do that" is to create the directory structure and put it in there manually - the class file itself is entirely valid.

Note that if you use the `-d` flag, javac will build the appropriate directory hierarchy for you, regardless of source location. For example:

```
javac -d bin ClassInPackage.java
```

will create any required directories under `bin` to match the package declared in `ClassInPackage.java`.

Having said all of thise, I'd still *strongly encourage* you to make the source directories match the packages, even though you can get away without it :)