# Java compiler - package namespace and directory structure

Tags: java, command-line

Is there a way to build a project into a namespace, say "org.example.this.particular.library" without actually creating that directory structure in the source tree? In other words, I want to put my files in "[project]/src/" rather than "[project]/org/example/this/particular/library/".

EDIT: The library contains multiple files, so the compiler needs to know where to look to resolve other package classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310518/dont-packages-have-to-match-the-subdirectories-the-java-file-is-in

Comment: I imagined there would be an option to map one path to another - something along the lines of "-sourcepath org/example/this/particular/library=src". The project contains multiple sources in the same package, so the compiler needs to resolve some dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you compile this file explicitly or use the Compiler API to compile your files.

Either way it if far more complicated than just using those directories.

If you use an IDE and a build tool you don't really need to care what the directories are.