# How do I compile Java code that uses JAR?

Tags: java

I am trying to compile and run java code that relies on a jar package. I put everything in the same directory and I am still getting this error.

I have no idea why this is. I imported all the jar files to my classpath too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be related to the classpath, it's that your package declaration is wrong. What happens if you change it to `package Java;`?

Comment: Your package names dictates the structure of directories as well. If you class is in package called `x.z` then you must have a corresponding directory structure of `./x/y` where that Java file resides. That being said, I believe package `java` is probably reserved named.

Comment: the package is "jama.examples" and you workspace is ".../Java" you should change your package name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310518/dont-packages-have-to-match-the-subdirectories-the-java-file-is-in

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted. It's a valid question that was giving me a lot of trouble. It's stuff like this gives SO a bad reputation.

Comment: `ypitcan@ypitcan-bstats:~/Documents/Programming/Java$ javac -cp Jama.jar: MagicSquareExample.java`

After some more work it seems like it compiles but can't run.

`ypitcan@ypitcan-bstats:~/Documents/Programming/Java$ java -cp Jama.jar: MagicSquareExample
Error: Could not find or load main class MagicSquareExample`

That's what I'm getting now. This is still an issue :(.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code use classes stored in a external jar file.
If you are using command line to compile and execute, you must add the jar file to classpath.

Ex.:

To compile:

> javac -classpath C:/folder/MyJarFile.jar MyClass.java

To run:

> java -classpath C:/folder/MyJarFile.jar MyClass

Also, make sure you are correctly importing the external classes, as

```
import thepkg.OtherClass;
```

I strongly advice to use an IDE, as Eclipse or netbeans do develop anything, even a basic simple example. 
Today there are some online IDEs, like Tutorials Point, but I don't know how to include external libs in theses environments.

Comment: See my comment earlier about class not found.

Comment: @Glassjawed - Get a first class IDE, like Eclipse or Netbeans. It's free and and eliminates all those silly issues.